# What is the correct way to pull "spring.datasouce.password" from a secrets bucket?

Tags: spring, configuration, passwords, google-cloud-storage, spring-jdbc

I have a Spring Boot App with different application-{env}.properties files. 
In each file, I have configs

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/db?cloudSqlInstance=app-qa:us-central1:app-qa1-cloudsql-0&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&user=${spring.datasource.username}&password=${spring.datasource.password}
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

but I would like to pull out hardcoding the password in the codebase, and make it a reference to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, for security.

a) Is this achieveable with Spring Boot? If so, how should I go about implementing this?

b) Is this the optimal way to hide my password? If not, how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a key/value pair to your storage bucket's metadata. See here for details on adding metadata to a Google Cloud Storage bucket: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata

Once you add it you can reference it from your properties with the key value like: ${MY_PASSWORD}

Here are some alternative ways of dealing with credentials:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-google-cloud-storage